# How do I customize three letter sequences in Vim Latex-Suite?

Tags: vim, latex-suite

I installed Latex-Suite for Vim, and I like it very much, but I'd like to be able to customize the environment mappings that came by default, and add new ones. For example I want to edit the equation environment that appears typing `EEQ` and move around some elements, like the `\label{}` command. How can I do this? I've been scanning everything inside my `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftplugin` but I can't find a way to do it (or I just don't understand what those files are).

Answer (score 1):

You want to check out the [documentation on Macro Customisation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-macros.html#Tex_Env_name), specifically the `Tex_Env_{name}` bit.

In short, if you want your theorem snippet to look like

```
\begin{theorem}
     <++>
\end{theorem}<++>
```

then you want a line like

```
let g:Tex_Env_theorem = "\\begin{theorem}\<CR><++>\<CR>\\end{theorem}"
```

in your vimrc.
Note the backslashes to escape carriage-return, and double-backslash for normal backslashes.

The `<F5>` functionality (press F5 after typing an environment name, i.e. `figure<F5>`) should work out of the box, but you may need to refresh the three-letter code. This is more hassle than it needs to be, but something like

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tex call IMAP('EFI', g:Tex_Env_figure,'tex')
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question you asked comes with a caveat, which is that Latex-Suite is an enormous amount of code that is very hard and annoying to modify, and which does not play nicely with other plugins. This falls into Latex-Suite's philosophy that it's the only plugin you need for editing latex within vim.

That said, you want to look in `/path/to/ftplugin/latex-suite/envmacros.vim`. Searching for `EEQ` will lead you on the path to understanding the set of calls that latex-suite performs. I would like to reiterate that many functions are deeply intertwined.

On the other hand, there is a very easy way to have very easily customizable environments, which are snippets. See the [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) page for a good example of how this works. These are designed for customization and extremely easy to write.